# Set Text Field value equal to double

Tags: flutter

I have a text field that inputs a number and want to set that value equal to a double, but whenever I try it does nothing and I am not sure why.

Below is how the textfield is implemented

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  controller: _incomeController,
  style: const TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    hintText: 'Balance',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
    ),
  ),
),
```

This is how I am trying to convert the text field to the double income.

```
income = _incomeController.text.trim() as double;
```

Comment: it difference controllers bro, `_balanceController`  and `_incomeController`

Answer (score 1):

First seem like you are using wrong controller :

`_balanceController` instead of  `_incomeController`

Second, you cannot cast string to double like that, instead try this:

```
income = double.tryParse(_balanceController.text.trim());
```